# Saving extracted features in CNN

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, tflearn

I've just started learning machine learning algorithms. I would like to train VGG-16 network for my own dataset. I am using `tflearn.DNN` to simulate the VGG net. 
I want to save the output (which is a tensor) of fully connected layer, that extracts 4096 features, into a file. I wanted to know how to save these features.

When i ran the following lines:

```
feed_dict = feed_dict_builder(X, Y, model.inputs, model.targets)
output = model.predictor.evaluate(feed_dict, convnet1)
print(output)
output.save('features.npy')
```

I got the following exception and error:

```
Exception in thread Thread-48:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/anupama/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 916, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/home/anupama/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 864, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/home/anupama/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tflearn/data_flow.py", line 187, in fill_feed_dict_queue
    data = self.retrieve_data(batch_ids)
  File "/home/anupama/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tflearn/data_flow.py", line 222, in retrieve_data
    utils.slice_array(self.feed_dict[key], batch_ids)
  File "/home/anupama/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tflearn/utils.py", line 180, in slice_array
    return [x[start] for x in X]
  File "/home/anupama/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tflearn/utils.py", line 180, in <listcomp>
    return [x[start] for x in X]
IndexError: index 2 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 2

[0.0]
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-23-f2d62c020964> in <module>()
      4 output = model.predictor.evaluate(feed_dict, convnet1)
      5 print(output)
----> 6 output.save('/home/anupama/Internship/feats')

AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'save'
```

Answer (score 0):

You should save the FC layer of the network as a separate tensor and use `DNN.predictor` to evaluate it. Sample code:

```py
import tflearn
from tflearn.utils import feed_dict_builder

# VGG model definition
...
previous_layer = ...
fc_layer1 = tflearn.fully_connected(previous_layer, 4096, activation='relu', name='fc1')
fc_layer2 = tflearn.fully_connected(fc_layer1, 4096, activation='relu', name='fc2')
network = ...

# Training
model = tflearn.DNN(network)
model.fit(x, y)

# Evaluation
feed_dict = feed_dict_builder(x, y, model.inputs, model.targets)
output = model.predictor.evaluate(feed_dict, [fc_layer2])
np.save('features.npy', output)
```

Comment: I ran the following lines:
feed_dict = feed_dict_builder(X, Y, model.inputs, model.targets)
output = model.predictor.evaluate(feed_dict, [convnet1])

But I got this exception:
Exception in thread Thread-33:

  File "/home/anupama/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tflearn/utils.py", line 180, in <listcomp>
    return [x[start] for x in X]
IndexError: index 2 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 2  
And when I print output, it's value is [0.0]

Comment: Edit your question and provide the code you're using, ideally with sample data, so that it can be reproduced

Comment: @Anupama Sorry, my bad, forgot how to save numpy properly. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks, i can save the features now. But running the lines of code raised an exception as mentioned in the question. And I'm getting only one value as output. So its not a numpy array of shape (1000, 4096) like what i wanted, but rather of shape 1. I'm not understanding why this is happening.

Comment: I couldn't reproduce it. Can you print `convnet1.shape`?

Comment: Yes, convnet1.shape prints (?, 4096).